# cuda is not available when running from docker

Tags: docker, pytorch, cuda

I have Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS with CUDA 11.4 and cuDNN 8500, python 3.8.10.
When running the following command (not from docker):

```
import torch
print(torch.__version__)
print(torch.backends.cudnn.version())
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

I'm getting:

```
1.13.1+cu117
8500
True
```

I build docker with the following dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.10

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

RUN python -m venv /venv
ENV PATH="/venv/bin:$PATH"

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install torch==1.13.1+cu117 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
RUN pip install notebook

EXPOSE 8873

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--port=8873", "--no-browser", "--allow-root"]
```

I run the docker with the followinng command:
`sudo docker run -p 8873:8873 myimagenew`

And run the same code:

```
import torch
print(torch.__version__)
print(torch.backends.cudnn.version())
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

But there the GPU is not detected (output):

```
1.13.1+cu117
8500
False
```

What is missing and how can I build docker with python 3.8.10 and pytorch which use the GPU ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to start your docker with GPU support. Use the --gpu=all flag in your docker run command:

```
sudo docker run -p 8873:8873 --gpu=all myimagenew
```

if this fails, make sure you have installed the nvidia-container-toolkit. See the instructions [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/latest/install-guide.html#docker)